# Incorrect Input String format

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a GST function which prompts user to enter the percentage of GST which will automatically calculate and display on a textbox. However, it keeps on displaying error saying about Incorrect Input string error on    `txtGST.Text`

```
        Dim GSTPrice As Double =  txtGst.Text
        Dim GrandTotal As Double = TotalPrice + GSTPrice  

        txtSubTotal.Text = "" & TotalPrice.ToString("f2")
        txtGst.Text = "" & GSTPrice.ToString("f2")
        txtTotalPrice.Text = "" & GrandTotal.ToString("f2")
```

Comment: The value in `txtGst` does not correctly convert to `Double`.  Use [Double.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to attempt to convert the value to a Double without crashing the program.  If `Double.TryParse()` returns false then the value isn't valid for a Double.  You can write it to the Console or display it in a MessageBox to help troubleshoot.

Comment: What is the purpose of `"" & Anything`. Your adding an empty string to the front of a string??? It is not needed.

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: But the same error occurs @Plutonix